# Why do variables need single quotes in `execute` SQL query?

Tags: sql, ruby, execute

Given `name = "Ben"`, this does not work:

```
DB.execute("SELECT id FROM departments WHERE name = #{name}")
```

but this does (added single quotes):

```
DB.execute("SELECT id FROM departments WHERE name = '#{name}'")
```

Why? Why doesn't Ruby call the variable in the first example? It's already a string. I don't see why that should make any difference. Isn't that equivalent to passing `"'Ben'"`? Wouldn't this be equivalent to passing `"Ben"`?

Comment: use like this `DB.execute("SELECT id FROM departments WHERE name = ?", name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Ruby problem, but an SQL syntax issue.

```
WHERE name = tom
```

and

```
WHERE name = 'tom'
```

are two different things.

In the first case, it is treated as a schema object name (presumably a column name here), in the second case it is a String literal.

You run into the same issue whenever you use one programming language to create a program for another programming language (here Ruby -> SQL) by direct String manipulation.

The correct way is to use bind variables.

```
WHERE name = ?
```

That also deals with the problem of `name` containing special characters.

```
name = "Little Bobby Tables, see http://xkcd.com/327/"
```

Comment: if t = "tom", why does t enter the SQL as tom, not "tom", and as a schema object name, rather than the string literal which it was set.

Comment: If you write `"Hello #{name}"`, it outputs "Hello Tom" without any quotes. That's just what it does. Just the contents of your string variable. If you want quotes, you have to put them there. How else is Ruby supposed to know that you want quotes?